# When BHE' signal in 8086 is activated or deactivated?

Tags: hardware, x86-16, microprocessors

I'm studying hardware specification for 8086 and I'm wondering What BHE' signal do? when is activated? deactivated?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming. It may be a better fit for [Retrocomputing Stack Exchange](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

The [8086](/questions/tagged/8086) can address bytes (8 bits) and words (16 bits) in memory.

To access a **byte at an even address**, the *A0* signal will be logically 0 and the *BHE* signal will be 1.
To access a **byte at an odd address**, the *A0* signal will be logically 1 and the *BHE* signal will be 0.
To access a **word at an even address**, the *A0* signal will be logically 0 and the *BHE* signal will also be 0.

| instruction | A0 | BHE | cycles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mov al, [1234h] | 0 | 1 | 10 |
| mov al, [1235h] | 1 | 0 | 10 |
| mov ax, [1234h] | 0 | 0 | 10 |

To access a **word at an odd address**, the processor will need to address the bytes separately. This will incur a penalty of 4 cycles!
The instruction `mov ax, [1235h]` will take 14 cycles.

Comment: So BHE stands for what, Byte High ~Enable, with inverted signalling so the high byte of the word is fetched if it's off?  (But the place it's fetched to on the bus depends on A0?  Or does the CPU itself handle muxing.)  I guess I could look that up if I actually cared enough about 8086 external busses.